# ExtJs: change combobox config in controller

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have grid with editable combobox editor. I need to change the editable config of the combobox based on combobox's store size. To achieve this I have two selectors on my grid, beforeitemclick and itemclick.

```
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'initialValue',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        name: 'initCombo',
                        store: 'InitialValue',
                        displayField: 'value',
                        valueField: 'value',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        allowBlank: true,
                        editable: false,

                    },
                     text: 'initial value'
                  }
```

The whole thing starts working from the second click on the grid and when I click the grid for the first time nothing happens . **How can I control the config one level earlier?**  .

```
            doBeforeSelectPropertyGrid: function(record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
               var me = this;
               var idProperty = item.get('idProperty');
               me.getFormInitCombo().getStore().load({params: {idProperty: idProperty},
                   scope: this,
                   callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                       if (records.length < 2) {
                           Ext.apply(me.getFormInitCombo(), {editable: true});
                       }
                       me.doSelectPropertyGrid(record, item, index, e, eOpts);
                   }
                })
            },
            doSelectPropertyGrid: function(record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                var me = this;
                me.getFormInitCombo();
            },
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the `beforeitemclick` indeed gets fired the first time you click the grid ?

Comment: no it was not, I changed the code and now I call itemclick in beforeitemclick method, but still its not working, I will update the code here